# Why I can not use 100%cpu in the memtier_benchmark test

Tags: c, memcached, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I want to test the memcached using the memtier_benchmark.

under my thought, if we use small bytes message under many concurrency requests, the cpu can be used almost close to 100%, but in fact the actual cpu usage is just about 10% in the kernel, and 4% in the user space, the iowait is almost 0. so I want to know why the cpu usage is so low?

environment:

CPU: 24 core, intel E5
OS: CentoS6.5 kernel 2.6.32
network: 10Gb Ethernet

I use one node as the memcached serve:

> memcached -v -t 24 -c 4096

and use 6 node as the client to visit in parallel, the command is

> memtier_benchmark -s x.x.x.x -p 11211 -P memcache_binary -x 1 --out-file /tmp/memcached.ans -c 20 -d 16 -t 8

Comment: I thought most cost will occurred in the kernel,  and kernel use the spin lock mostly, so the lock wait for cpu should be tiny?

Comment: What is the max memory throughput? If you hit memory from 24 threads, they will likely have to wait for the data to arrive.

Comment: @BoPersson I do not know how to measure the memory throughout, this is  depend on cpu architecture, maybe linux perf can observe this? but I do not observe this yet.  I do not think the memory bandwidth can limit, because when I reduce the thread from 24 to the default 4 thread, the cpu usage is almost the same. btw: there is 128GB in every machine.

Comment: As I read the documentation for that utility, it is for accessing a database on a server (preferably a remote server).  I do not see any facility for benchmarking the cache operation on the local machine/CPU

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, it just to benchmark the capacity of memcached/redis, but the TCP/IP stack will cost a lot of CPU under high requests.